# SQL Server Dateadd 5 Min Ago

Tags: sql-server

I work flood protect script and i need check user submit form last 5 minutes.
My SQL Server **datetime** column value is `2016-02-16 20:01:56.000`

and i tried;

```
select number from person where number='111111111' and date > dateadd(minute, -5, '2016-02-16 18:01:56.000')
```

or

```
select number from person where number='111111111' and date > dateadd(mm, -5, getdate())
```

This query always getting value is `'111111111'` i change time, example **'2016-02-16 15:01:56.000'** or **'2016-02-16 12:01:56.000'** but getting **111111111** value already?? Where is my wrong?

**EDIT**

I found problem, insert and set datetime from my local time but my server in a another country, and time zone different 10 hour :)

Comment: Your are selecting the same field (`number`) that you are filtering on in your `WHERE` statement.  Whatever column you want to return needs to be in your `SELECT` statement. Also, you are referencing `mm` for minute, which is the date part for month. you should use `mi` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong datepart

minutes = mi,n

month = mm

Comment: i changed value to 2016-02-16 20:00:00.000 and select number from person where number='111111111' and date > dateadd(mi, -500, getdate())  already 111111 getting....

Comment: @Beecee71 Could you perhaps post the whole SQL query for clarification?

Comment: Select number from person where number ='111111111' and date > dateadd(mi,-5,getdate () )